# Unknown permission in package for android GCM register

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-c2dm

I am trying to get registration id for android device but I am getting following warnings:

```
    02-21 18:23:46.437: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.437: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.437: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.437: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.437: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.437: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.445: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.445: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.445: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.445: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.445: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.445: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.445: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.445: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.453: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.453: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.453: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.453: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.453: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.453: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.460: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.468: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.476: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.476: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.476: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.476: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.476: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.484: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.492: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.492: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.492: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.492: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.492: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.492: W/PackageManager(1495): Not granting permission to package (protectionLevel flags)
02-21 18:23:46.500: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.500: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package 
02-21 18:23:46.500: W/PackageManager(1495): Unknown permission in package
```

my application manifest file is as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="package1.package2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<permission
    android:name="package1.package2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="package1.package2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="SampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="SearchResult"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ShowProduct"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>     

    <receiver
        android:name="package1.package2.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="package1.package2" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
    <service android:name="package1.package2.GCMServiceHandler"></service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I am also getting error SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE when trying to register the device.

Comment: Cause of your **package name**. Try to change your package name.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried changing package name but no luck! I used completely different package name

Answer (score 0):

What obvious to me is put a "." in front of like this

```
<service android:name=".GCMServiceHandler"></service>
```

or use full path

```
<service android:name="com.example.webserviceaccess.GCMServiceHandler"></service>
```

Permission name must also be correct. If you change package name, clean project and right click project - Android tools>Fix project properties

I dont use this in my project and it's working, try remove the

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.SEND" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
```

Comment: try remove the
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.SEND" />

Comment: you have an Unknown permission and that was one Unknown permission

Comment: Change android:targetSdkVersion="8" to 18 and try

Comment: yea, remove this line <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

Comment: but it is as per the documentation of android GCM

Comment: Check the doc again, both of them `SEND` and `REGISTRATION` are only in the `<receiver` Look at this [manifest](http://fryerblog.com/post/30057483199/implementing-push-notifications-with-gcm) pay attention also how he use the package name

Answer (score 0):

try it by changing protectionLevel "normal" to "signature" as

```
  android:protectionLevel="signature"
```

Comment: No luck! Tried changing ProtectionLevel "signature"